# postman stuck on sending request - express js mongodb

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express, mongoose

[postman stuck at sending request when im not putting `res.status(200).json({message: "success", status: true});` outside the if statement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GfZbc.jpg)

```
    var express = require('express');
    var app = express();
    var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
    var multer = require('multer');
    var upload = multer();
    var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
    var mongoose = require('mongoose');
    app.set('view engine', 'pug');
    app.set('views', 'views');
    app.use(express.json());
    app.use(bodyParser.json( { extended: true} ));
    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true }));
    app.use(upload.array());
    app.use(cookieParser());

    mongoose.set('strictQuery', true);

    mongoose.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/my_db',
    {
        useNewUrlParser: true,
        useUnifiedTopology: true
    },(err) => {
        if(err){
            
        }else{
            console.log("connected");
        }
    }
    );

    var userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
        username: {type: String, required: true, index: { unique: true }},
        password: {type: String, required: true}
    });


    var User = mongoose.model("User", userSchema);

    app.post('/signup', (req, res) => {
    
        var userInfo = req.query;

        if(!userInfo.username || !userInfo.password ){
            res.status("400");
            res.send("Invalid Details");
        }else {
            const newUser = new User({
                username: userInfo.username,
                password: userInfo.password
            });

            
            User.findOne({username: userInfo.username} , (err, response) => {
                if(response == null){
                    newUser.save().then( ()=> {
                        res.status(200).json({ message: 'Success!', status: true});
                        // res.status(200).end();
                    }).catch( error => {
                        res.status(400).json({message: err, status: false});
                        console.log("existing user");
                    });
                }
                //res.status(200).json({message: "success", status: true});
            });
        }
    });

    app.listen(3000);
```

How do I stop the code on the "then" part or catch, I wanted to catch the result and display it on front end. postman stuck at sending request when im not putting res.status(200).json({message: "success", status: true}); outside the if statement

Comment: You're never sending a response if `response == null` is false.

Comment: No actually, it's working well, that part is the condition where I check if the user exist in the mongodb if not then save. the data does get save on the database but "res.status(200).json({ message: 'Success!', status: true});" is not working.. I needed to add the res.status outside the if statement (the one that I commented)  so that postman wont hanged or stuck on sending request.

Comment: You also need to return `res.send("Invalid Details");` otherwise you send back an response and the functions continues to execute in the background

Comment: Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client - this is what I get

Comment: and now, the postman is getting stuck to "sending request" if the user exist or the catch part - https://prnt.sc/ngjvzZ9yw3tz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing is you are passing JSON as query argument to your API which is not a good idea.
And in the code, you should consider and handle the `corner` conditions with the else statements.

There's no `else` block to `if(response == null)` statement. And also handle the `err` conditions.

Try adding printing the `userInfo.username` and `userInfo.password` and add the screenshot here if the issue is not resolved.

Comment: Thanks a lot! adding the else statement is what I need after all. My bad for the stupid question. I guess I got rusty.